# compress file with rar.exe in command line batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, compression, updates, winrar

I'm compress single file update.ver to update.rar
used rar.exe in command line ( batch files )
dictionary size 1024KB
please help me to make this batch file

```
@echo off
REM Path to WinRAR executable in Program Files
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe";%path%



echo 1. Compress files in dir individually (no subdirs)
echo.
echo.
set /P
if "%FILE%"=="1" goto indiv


REM Compress files in directory individually (no subdirectories)
:indiv
echo.
echo.
FOR %%i IN (*.*) do (
rar a "%%~ni" "%%i"
)
goto eof


:eof


endlocal

Erase v6.rar
Erase update.ver
rename update.rar update.ver
```

this code not work in windows vps

Comment: with `set path`, please set the path only - not including the file: `set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%`

Comment: please insert other code to used rar.exe

Answer (score 1):

Some example code:

```
@echo off &setlocal
REM Path to WinRAR executable in Program Files
set "path=C:\Program Files\WinRAR;%path%"

echo 1. Compress files in dir individually (no subdirs)
echo(
echo(
set /P "answer="
if not "%answer%"=="1" goto eof

REM Compress files in directory individually (no subdirectories)
:indiv
echo(
echo(
FOR %%i IN (*) do (
    rar a "%%~ni.rar" "%%~i" || echo Error building archive!
)

Erase v6.rar
Erase update.ver
rename update.rar update.ver
```

Comment: help me  please dears